# Paginate a response from api in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, pagination

I'm building an application flutter ( movie db api ) from where i'm getting many pages of movies , upon launch of app , i'm fetching the first page which contains almost 20 movies , now i would like to someone increment the page so that i can fetch more videos ( i want something similar to paging libary 3 in android ) , is this possible to do in flutter , any help is appreciated .

- This is my code in flutter

```
 Expanded(
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context,ref,_){
                  var popularMovies = ref.watch(MovieController.popularMoviesProvider(counter)).value;
                  if(popularMovies != null){
                    return ListView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: popularMovies.results?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        var finalResult = popularMovies.results!;
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            Get.to(() => const DetailsScreen(),
                                arguments: [
                                  {"movieId" : finalResult[index].id}
                                ]);
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Material(
                                  elevation: 4,
                                  shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius : BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: Image.network("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${finalResult[index].backdropPath}",
                                        height: 170,width : 120 ,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width : 250,
                                          child: Text(finalResult[index].title!,style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontFamily: 'mulish_bold'
                                          ),maxLines: 2,),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset("assets/icons/rating.png",height: 20,width: 20,),
                                              Expanded(child: Text("${finalResult[index].voteAverage}/10 Imdb",style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mulish_regular',
                                                  color: Color(0xFF9C9C9C)),))
                                            ],
                                          ),

                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                        Consumer(
                                          builder: (context,ref,_){
                                            var genres = ref.watch(MovieController.moviesGenreProvider).value;
                                            if(genres != null){
                                              return showGenres(index,genres.genres,popularMovies);
                                            } else {
                                              return const Center(
                                                child: SizedBox(
                                                  height: 2,
                                                  width: 100,
                                                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                                    color: Colors.green,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                        Card(
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                                          ),
                                          color: Colors.green.shade400,
                                          child :  Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                            child: Text(finalResult[index].releaseDate!,style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mulish_regular',
                                                color: Colors.white,fontSize: 13),),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  else {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange,),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
```

PS : I'm using flutter riverpod for state management .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your api supports pagination, A common way of paginating while using ListView.builder is not supply itemCount, when your index is greater than currently fetched items length, then fetch again from API. refer this codelab from Flutter. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab

```dart
ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, index) {
        if (index >= currentFetchedItems.length) {
          // fetch from API and update your data
          currentFetchedItems.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
        }
        return currentFetchedItems[index];
      },
    );
```